# Identify USB wireless charger and possibly ways to use, modify, or control it

Tags: usb, charger, wireless-charging

A friend found this device, and I have determined that it seems to be a wireless charger for a phone, smart watch, or similar device. The markings show it to be a "Wireless Gear" Model BL2186, and has an input of 5V/2A or 9V/1.67A, and output is 9V/1.12A/10W. I could not find any information on-line.

[image: Wireless charger]

[image: Wireless charger]

I connected it to a USB port and an internal LED flashed red/green at 1-2 second intervals, and plugging into a USB phone charger power supply lights the red LED. I connected a scope to an air core inductor (several hundred turns on a 1 cm dia x 2 cm long spool), and it picked up pulses as follows (looks like about 50 kHz, but this is a new instrument and I haven't used it much):

[image: Waveform]

[image: Waveform]

I'd like to know if there might be any practical uses for this thing, and perhaps how to communicate with it to maintain continuous output. I suppose it would be possible to make an inductor with an optimal shape to receive this wireless signal and convert it to a usable voltage and current, perhaps to charge some NiMH cells, or to drive an LED light strip.

(edit) As for an electronics design question, (1) how would I design a pickup coil for effective transfer of power to a device like a battery charger or LED strip, and (2) is there a way to determine and implement a communication protocol to control the transmitter.

Some articles that may help:

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4701.pdf

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/news/how-does-qi-wireless-charging-standard-work/

Does anyone have experience with this?

(edit2) After reading some of the material for the Qi protocol, it looks like it involves a major engineering effort, so I doubt that there is any way to do anything useful with this device. At best I might be able to flash an LED using the ping signal which occurs at about 200 ms intervals.

(edit3) There are [universal wireless charging adapters](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1901?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6IOXgdCW_AIVwdrICh0xPQA1EAQYAyABEgLpcfD_BwE) available that appear to be the only practical way to make use of this thing, and I don't think it's worth it for me to buy one.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable, electronics design question to your post